# AppBar flickers when using Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil()

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm tying to clear all of the previous routes after the user has logged on to my app. However, I'm having an issue with the following code in my Flutter app:

```
void clearRoutes()
  {
    //createLinks();
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/my_home', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => clearRoutes());

    return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text("iWhiz Home"),
          ),
          body: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: links.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(links[index]),
                );
              }
          ),
        );
  }
```

The above code results in this issue:

[image]

The line of code that is giving me this issue is `Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/my_home', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);`

Can this issue be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution. This is the code that was giving me a problem:

```
class Login extends StatelessWidget
{
  void homePage(BuildContext context)
  {
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/my_home");
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text("Login"),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child:
          Column(
            children: [
              Text("Welcome to the Login Page"),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: ()
                {
                  homePage(context);
                },
                child: Text("Login"),
              ),
            ],
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class MyHome extends StatelessWidget
{
  void removePreviousRoutes(BuildContext context)
  {
    //The problem code.
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/my_home', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => removePreviousRoutes(context));

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text("My Home"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child:
          Text("Welcome to the Home Page"),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

The initial page that would be displayed is **Login**. After the user clicks on 'Welcome to the Login Page' they would be directed to the **MyHome** page. The issue comes from `Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/my_home', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);` on the **MyHome** page.

**Solution:**

```
class Login extends StatelessWidget
{
  void homePage(BuildContext context)
  {
    //The solution.
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/my_home");

    Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/my_home', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text("Login"),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child:
          Column(
            children: [
              Text("Welcome to the Login Page"),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: ()
                {
                  homePage(context);
                },
                child: Text("Login"),
              ),
            ],
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHome extends StatelessWidget
{
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text("My Home"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child:
          Text("Welcome to the Home Page"),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

The solution was to push the new route **AND** remove all previous routes from **Login**, **INSTEAD OF** pushing the new route in **Login** and removing previous routes from **Registration**. After doing this, I no longer received the flickering issue.